# How to get large icon in NotificationListenerService

Tags: android, notifications, icons

I have a class extended NotificationListenerService, how can i get a large notification icon in onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn, RankingMap rankingMap) method?

To get small icon i use:

```
 public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn, RankingMap rankingMap) {
    extras = sbn.getNotification().extras;
    smallIcon = extras.getInt(Notification.EXTRA_SMALL_ICON, 0);
...
}
```

and it return the id of drawable in that package, but how can i get a large icon?
i tried smth like that:

```
 final Bitmap iconLarge = (Bitmap) extras.getParcelable(Notification.EXTRA_LARGE_ICON);
```

and that

```
final Bitmap iconLarge = sbn.getNotification().largeIcon;
```

its always return null, i target API 21+

```
sbn.getNotification().getLargeIcon()
```

not work, only 23+.
Any help?

Comment: Did you solve this? I have the same issue and `largeIcon` was deprecated.

Comment: Yes,  i added an answer, check it.

Answer (score 2):

According to Android Documentation,

[getLargeIcon()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#getLargeIcon()) method is added in API Level 23 only.

This is why the API is returning you null when you are trying to access it in Android Lollipop(API Level 21) and working fine in case of Marshmallow(API Level 23)

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
Bundle extras = sbn.getNotification().extras;
Bitmap bigIcon = (Bitmap) extras.get(Notification.EXTRA_LARGE_ICON);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
   (bundle["android.largeIcon"] as Icon).loadDrawable(baseContext).toBitmap()
 } else {
    bundle.get(Notification.EXTRA_LARGE_ICON) as Bitmap
}
```